# Recursive Directory Iterator Issue on Windows 11 - Fails to Show Symbolic Linked Sub-folders

Tags: c++, c++17

I am encountering an issue with a recursive directory iterator code snippet on Windows 11. The code is designed to traverse through sub-folders, including symbolic links. However, on Windows 11, it fails to display symbolic linked sub-folders. I'd like to understand why this is happening and how to resolve it.

```
#include <filesystem>

// ...

for (std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator i("D:\\media\\", std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink), end; i != end; ++i)
{
    if (std::filesystem::is_directory(i->path())) {
        // Perform some actions related to directories
    }
}
```

**Desired Behavior:**
I want the code to successfully traverse through all sub-folders, including symbolic linked sub-folders, when run on Windows 11.

**Specific Problem:**
The code snippet provided above works perfectly on Windows 10, showing symbolic linked sub-folders as expected. However, when running the same code on Windows 11, it fails to display the symbolic linked sub-folders.

**Error Message:**
There are no error messages or exceptions thrown. The code simply doesn't include symbolic linked sub-folders in the iteration on Windows 11.

**Additional Information:**

**Compiler used:** C++ 17 (Visual Studio 2022)
I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to make this code work correctly on Windows 11. Thank you!

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @DanielA.White C++17 standard under Visual studio ver 17.1.6

Comment: Could it be that it throws an exception? `try`/`catch` and print it out to see what happened (if that's what's happening).

Comment: @TedLyngmo: It doesn't throw, it simply skips the soft-linked folders.

Comment: Hmm. Are they unixy softlinks? I just tried with that, but it seems to work fine for me and I'm also using VS2022 in W11. I added the option `directory_options::skip_permission_denied` too though, but I don't think that should matter in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I am not sure about unixy softlinks but in my PC create using `mklink` the command prompt. I have verified that it's indeed a symbolic link by clicking the folder properties. Without the `std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink` it does not work even in windows 10

Comment: Hmm, if I do `mklink soft real` (where `real` is a normal directory) I can't do `cd soft`. I just tried in a normal command window

Comment: All work fine in the command prompt even the `cd` command with the soft-links

Comment: Can you really `cd` down into the directory that you created with `mklink soft real`? Are you sure you don't want a Junction instead? Anyway I get `Access denied` when I use the `recursive_directory_iterator` to try to iterate through the same `soft`. If I make it into a Junction, it works fine.

Comment: Since junctions are specifically designed for directories, it may not work in my case. But I am not sure.

Comment: But, you are talking about a "symbolic linked sub-folders" ...?

Comment: I use `mklink` with `/D` switch to create a symbolic directory.

Comment: Ah, sorry... I read the manual wrong - Hmm, when I do that, the `recursive_directory_iterator` works fine for me.